# manipulacion de valores con un select

Tags: javascript, select

El asunto es que tengo una tabla que es de hoteles y con un `while` trae el nombre y el precio del hotel en su ultima posición, el asunto es que cuando el usuario elija el hotel en automático me arroje el precio del hotel, guardar ese precio en una variable y multiplicarlo con otro `select` que solamente me trae numero en personas. dejo el código:

```
 <select name="hoteles" class="form-control" id="cont" required> <!--COMBO 
   BOX hoteles-->
             <?php 
             $consulta = "SELECT hotel,precio FROM `hoteles_mayas`";
             $query=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
             while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

                 $precio = $fila['precio'];
                 $hotel =  $fila['hotel']; 
            ?>  

             <option selected value="<?php $precio ?>"><?php  echo  $hotel ?></option>

            <?php    
                 }  
                  mysqli_free_result($query);

            ?>  



         </select>

                 <br>
                  <input id="selector" name=""></input>
                 <input  id="value"></input>

              <br>
                <input type="radio" id="" name="tipo_transfer" value="OW"><label id="titulo4">ONE WAY</label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                <input type="radio" id="tipo_transfer_rt" name="tipo_transfer" value="RT"><label id="titulo4">ROUND TRIP </label>
                <br>

            <span id="tituloCombo">Adults:</span>
            <select name="hoteles" class="form-control" id="contN"> <!--COMBO BOX hoteles-->
             <?php 
             $consulta = "select * From numero_clientes";
             $query=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
             while ($h=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
                $num_adult = $h['numero_personas'];



            ?>                      
              <option><?php  echo $num_adult ?> </option>

            <?php  
                    $coste = $num_adult * $precio;       
                 }         
            ?>        
         </select> 
     <br>
     <label id="titulo5"> &nbsp;<?php echo '$'. $coste ?></label> &nbsp;<label id="titulo5">USD</label>
     <br>     
             <span id="tituloCombo">Children:</span>
             <select name="ninos" class="form-control" id="contN"> <!--COMBO BOX niños-->
             <?php 

             $consulta = "SELECT * FROM numero_clientes";
             $query=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
             while ($c=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                       $num_nino =$c['numero_personas']; 
                        $id = $c['id'];     
            ?>                      
              <option><?php  echo $num_nino; ?> </option>


            <?php 
                       $num = $num_nino;
                       $precio2 = $num * $precio;
                       $total = $precio2 + $coste;

                 }         
            ?>        
              </select>
                  <br> 
    <label id="titulo5">&nbsp;<?php echo '$'. $precio2 ?></label> &nbsp;<label id="titulo5">USD</label>
                   <br>
                   <br>
    <label id="titulo5"> Total: &nbsp;<?php echo '$'. $total ?></label> &nbsp;<label id="titulo5">USD</label>
```

Comment: Dónde querés guardar el resultado de `precio x personas`? En un `input`? Si PHP no es parte del problema, te diría que cambies el código que pegaste por uno solo con el HTML necesario para simplificar el tema. Estás usando `jQuery`?

Comment: si.. ya lo simplifique te lo agradezco mucho..es para una transportadora.. gracias mil gracias..

Answer (score 1):

Te he escrito un [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2doz46ty/1/) con una posible solución a lo que pides. He sustituído tu código PHP por un poco de HTML con valores de ejemplo para poder usarlo.

Tengo un par de notas importantes:

- Seguridad: Vuelve a hacer el cálculo en el servidor al recibir los datos. Es muy fácil modificar el HTML antes de enviar nada, con lo cual si no lo verificas, un usuario podría cambiar el precio a lo que quisiera.
- He dejado el HTML que usas más o menos como estaba (salvo algunos tags  incorrectos e ids repetidas); pero recomiendo fuertemente que aprendas algo de estructura de html5 moderna. Tienes un abuso de `<br>` (nueva línea) que probablemente debería ser sustituído por bloques, bien `<p>`, bien `<div>`, dependiendo de la intención; tienes ids repetidos, etiquetas mal cerradas, labels innecesarios con ids genéricos, etc.

Aprender HTML puede llevar tiempo, pero es una fundación imprescindible si quieres dedicarte a esto.

Comment: Mil  gracias,  y otras mil por tus observaciones me fuero de mucho ayuda.. tomare mucho en cuenta lo que escribiste, no habia pensado en este tipo de seguridad .

Comment: delCano.... me fue de mucha ayuda tu respuesta, y solo le hice unas modificaciones tomando encuenta tus recomendaciones, ahora la cituasion, es que al momento de seleccionar el hotel y guardar a la base de datos me toma el valor del precio en lugar del hotel, y la otracituacion es como obtego la variable de los precios para guardalos en db.  te agrezco mucho si me puedes orientar, para resolverlo.

Comment: @jorgeenriquechancastillo efectivamente, al servidor sólo se envían los valores de los campos del formulario. Para el tema del hotel, probablemente lo mejor sería pasar el precio a un campo data (e.j., `data-precio`) y dejar como `value` el `id` del hotel. Para lo otro, no debería importar, pues el servidor debería calcular el precio por si mismo; pero siempre puedes meter los valores calculados por JS en un `input` en vez de un `label`.

Comment: delCano realmente siento  molestar de nuevo, pero aun no consigo solucionar ese problema.. el valor del select de hoteles, se guarda en el campo hotel de  db, aun obteniendo el valor con [data-precio]. y no eh logrado pasar los id, precio ninos y adultos a un inputs para guardarlos en db. gracias por leer..

Comment: @jorgeenriquechancastillo Realmente es otra pregunta esto, tendría que ver tu código para saber qué falla.

Comment: delCano funciona bien y hace su trabajo, la situación viene al momento de guardar a la db. Los select son dinamicos con bd trae el hotel y el precio, al momento de ejecutar el primer select con el primer while hace su funcion de traer el hotel elegido con su precio, y realiza la función de  calcular el precio por las personas con el script que me ayudaste.... ahora cuando guardo el resultado de la funcion, el <option value="$precio" >$hotel<option> guarda el value en el campo hotel en db. y si pongo el hotel en el value me guarda el hotel pero ya no hace la funcion y me sale NaN .

Answer (score 0):

```
        <select name="hotel" class="cont form-control" id="hoteles"  required> <!--COMBO BOX hoteles-->
             <?php 
             $consulta = "SELECT hotel,precio From hoteles where id = id_zona";
             $query=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
             while ($h=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
                $id = $h['id'];
                $hotel = $h['hotel'];
                $precio = $h['precio'];
            ?>                      
          <option  value="<?php echo $precio;?>" ><?php  echo $hotel; ?></option>
            <?php            
                 }         
            ?>        
         </select> 
            <p></p>

            <span id="tituloCombo" class="">Adults:</span>
            <select name="num_adultos" class="  form-control" id="adultos" required> 
             <?php 
             $consulta = "select * From numero_clientes";
             $query=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
             while ($h=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
                $num_adult = $h['numero_personas'];

            ?>                      
              <option><?php  echo $num_adult ?> </option>

            <?php           
                 }         
            ?>        
         </select> 

    <p></p>
     <label  disabled  name="pre_adulto" id="pre_adulto" ></label> <!--Precio Adultos-->           
     <p></p>    
             <span id="tituloCombo">Children:</span>
             <select name="num_ninos" class="contN form-control" id="ninos"> <!--COMBO BOX niños-->
             <?php 

             $consulta = "SELECT * FROM numero_clientes";
             $query=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
             while ($c=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                       $num_nino =$c['numero_personas'];             
            ?>                      
              <option><?php  echo $num_nino; ?> </option>
            <?php 
                 }         
            ?>        
              </select>
    <label class="titulo4" disabled name="pre_ninos"  id="pre_ninos"></label> <!--Precio Ninos-->
    <label class="titulo4" id="precio-total" disabled></label>
```

funciona bien con el script!! pero al momento de guardar a la db el hotel; me guarda el value $precio en el campo del hotel, y los valores precio ninos y precio adultos pasarlos a variables php.